# Stripe - JSON Circular reference

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

Im using Stripe Checkout.js to create a payment. I'm creating a handler, that on success sends a token to the server:

```
let handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
                key: 'my_key',
                image: 'image.png',
                locale: 'auto',
                token: token => {

                    console.log(token.id);

                    // ... send token to server
                }
            });
```

Then I use the handler to create a token:

```
handler.open({
    name: 'Test',
    description: 'test',
    billingAddress: false,
    currency: 'eur',
    amount: '1200',
});
```

This handler triggers the test checkout.js popup, that I fill in and click Pay. It ends successfully, meaning the button displays green.

But between the moment the button shows green, and the moment that the token is printed to the console (on the handler success callback), an error is thrown:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

The main part of the stacktrace is this:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at Object.stringify (http://localhost:5000/dist/client/bundle.js:46294:29)
    at RPC.sendMessage (https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:1:18068)
    at RPC.sendMessage (https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:1:16180)
    at https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:1:17137
    at RPC.ready (https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:1:17416)
    at RPC.invoke (https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:1:17084)
    at RPC.invoke (https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:1:16180)
    at RPC.processMessage (https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:1:18899)
    at RPC.processMessage (https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js:1:16180)
```

By inspecting the code, we see the issue is here:

```
        RPC.prototype.sendMessage = function(method, args) {
            var err, id, message, _ref;
            if (args == null ) {
                args = []
            }
            id = ++this.rpcID;
            if (typeof args[args.length - 1] === "function") {
                this.callbacks[id] = args.pop()
            }
            message = JSON.stringify({
                method: method,
                args: args,
                id: id
            });
```

It seems that Checkout.js creates a message object, that happens to have a circular reference, then it attempts to call JSON.stringify on it, which causes the error.

This error is non fatal and the payment goes through, but do you know what this could be and how to fix it?

Or is there a known workaround.

this is the [full stack trace](http://pastebin.ca/3413936)

Note that calling `stringify` before passing an object to `postMessage` *might* not be necessary according to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

`postMessage` uses a serialization mechanism that supports circular references according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm).

Comment: So you are stringifying some object that has references to itself. Just stringify it without those references. What is `args`?

Comment: the stringify is on stripe checkout code, not on application code. I've reported the issue to Stripe, but have posted this here as maybe someone knows of a workaround. Also with Angular 2 being in Beta, you never know

Comment: Did you try to debug this piece of code with JSON.stringify?

Comment: I have the same issue, however in addition the payment is not showing up on the dashboard. Are your transactions showing up on the dashboard?

Comment: yes at least on the test dashboard. I have not tried yet with real transactions. Also I've tried with Chrome and Firefox, but not with other browsers

Comment: Regarding this line you have as a comment:
`// ... send token to server`
How do you manage to pass the token to your server? I can't seem to access/pass `this` inside the handler that has my http service, or do you just send it through the form's action attribute?

Comment: This error was fixed in Stripe Checkout and should just work now

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is in checkout.js (at line 780 in the de-minified file):

```
message = JSON.stringify({
    method: method, 
    args: args,
    id: id
});
```

When running in Angular2, zone.js has wrapped the callback with zone information. This means that the args parameter looks like:

`[5, ZoneTask]`

And, ZoneTask has a member, .zone, which contains a circular reference: `zone -> _zoneDelegate -> zone`

```
JSON.stringify(args[1].zone)
> Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON(…)
```

So, fundamentally Stripe's checkout.js makes a non-circularity assumption which is no longer valid when Zone.js has been meddling. Stripe are going to have to fix this.

In the meantime you can use the following *horrendous* hack. It's so horrendous and so hacky that it makes my eyes bleed, but
it's the best I could come up with to fix it without modifying Stripe's code. Essentially, you globally replace JSON.stringify with a version that breaks any zone->_zoneDelegate->zone cycles in the object it is being asked to stringify:

```
const _stringify = JSON.stringify;
JSON.stringify = function (value, ...args) {
  if (args.length) {
    return _stringify(value, ...args);
  } else {
    return _stringify(value, function (key, value) {
      if (value && key === 'zone' && value['_zoneDelegate'] 
          && value['_zoneDelegate']['zone'] === value) {
        return undefined;
      }
      return value;
    });
  }
};
```

Apologies if your eyes are now bleeding. It works.

Comment: Your hack worked like a charm for me. I just pasted it into ngOnInit in my payment component, and also had to ignore a 'supplied parameters do not match any signature of the call target' error from the Typescript compiler on the 'return _stringify...' line. Much thanks!

Comment: The error can also be removed by adding <any> in front of JSON.stringify when it is assigned to const _stringify.

Comment: This error was fixed in Stripe Checkout and should just work now, no need for workarounds