# Converting circular structure to JSON in Stripe

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate Stripe payment method inside my Ionic2 application.

When I click on my payment button the stripe payment box appears (I insert card number, expire date and CVC) and when I click the "Pay" button it turns from blue to green and everything it seems to work, but if I inspect my browser console I read this error:

```
EXCEPTION: Converting circular structure to JSONErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:47next @ application_ref.js:272schedulerFn @ async.js:82SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257t.handleError @ polyfills.js:3e.runTask @ polyfills.js:3invoke @ polyfills.js:3
error_handler.js:52 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:52next @ application_ref.js:272schedulerFn @ async.js:82SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:74NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:278onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:257t.handleError @ polyfills.js:3e.runTask @ polyfills.js:3invoke @ polyfills.js:3
error_handler.js:53 TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at RPC.sendMessage (checkout.js:2)
    at RPC.sendMessage (checkout.js:2)
    at checkout.js:2
    at RPC.ready (checkout.js:2)
    at RPC.invoke (checkout.js:2)
    at RPC.invoke (checkout.js:2)
    at RPC.processMessage (checkout.js:2)
    at RPC.processMessage (checkout.js:2)
    at RPC.message (checkout.js:2)
```

I know that my question is basically the same of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258252/stripe-json-circular-reference) one but, since 7 months passed by, I would ask you if there is a better way of solving this question since the person who wrote the accepted answer said that this way of solving is *horrendous*.

By the way, if I would follow his answer, should I have to replace this

```
const _stringify = JSON.stringify;
JSON.stringify = function (value, ...args) {
  if (args.length) {
    return _stringify(value, ...args);
  } else {
    return _stringify(value, function (key, value) {
      if (value && key === 'zone' && value['_zoneDelegate'] 
          && value['_zoneDelegate']['zone'] === value) {
        return undefined;
      }
      return value;
    });
  }
};
```

with this:

```
message = JSON.stringify({
    method: method, 
    args: args,
    id: id
});
```

???

Or should I keep both blocks (one before the other one)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's unfortunately still the only answer.

You just need to include:

```
const _stringify = JSON.stringify;
JSON.stringify = function (value, ...args) {
  if (args.length) {
    return _stringify(value, ...args);
  } else {
    return _stringify(value, function (key, value) {
      if (value && key === 'zone' && value['_zoneDelegate'] 
          && value['_zoneDelegate']['zone'] === value) {
        return undefined;
      }
      return value;
    });
  }
};
```

In your code somewhere ahead of where you launch Checkout; the other code block you included there is where the issue resides, but that's inside Checkout itself so you don't need to worry about that.